# Processing rule in DataPower

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, ibm-datapower

I Have MQFSH as a backend,but the Queue is not yet created.
As a result the transaction is failing with an error of 2085 "unknown object".

Even after this failure , I can see there is no error rule getting triggered in the probe.

May I know the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking in to various blogs,got to know that
there is a settings under Advaced as  " Process Backend Errors".
After setting it "Off" , the error rule started getting triggered.

Thanks & regards,
Sreevathsa A

Comment: Sreevathsa, could you please mention under which component's advance setting it should be set as off ?

Comment: It can been seen in MPGW - > Advanced

Process Backend Errors

In some cases, the backend server returns a response code that indicates an error.

When enabled, the default, the service ignores the error condition and processes the response rule. If successful, returns the successful response to the client.

When disabled, the DataPower service notices the error condition and processes the error rule. If successful, propagates the response code from the backend server to the client.